# How to properly and efficiently configure the synchronization of threads in the computer shader on hlsl?

Tags: c#, hlsl

I am trying to do a GPU computation using HLSL, but I am faced with a performance degradation issue.
I have an array with 1,200,000 values ​​that simulates a 2D array [1200, 1000].

So...

My task is to produce distribution from each value [X, Y] to [X + shift_X, Y + 1], multiplying by the coefficient from the array of coefficients. This must be done strictly sequentially along the Y-axis.
If this is written in the form of pseudocode, then it will be something like this:

```
float[] data = new data[x_count * y_count];
...
for (int y = 0, y < y_count - 1, y++)
{
   for (int x = 0, x < x_count, x++)
   {
      int spread_shift = (spread.Length - 1) / 2u;
      for (int s = 0; s < spread.Length; s++)
      {
         int shift_ind = x + s - spread_shift;
         data[x + (y + 1) * x_count] += data[shift_ind + id.y * x_count] * spread[s];
      }
   }
}
```

In order to avoid the race, I added a barrier for the group. And it works, but very slowly.

Right now my c # code looks like this:

```
int x_count = 1200;
int y_count = 1000;

shader.Dispatch (spreading_index, x_count, y_count - 1, 1);
```

and in my shader like this:

```
[numthreads(1, 1, 1)]
void Spreading (uint3 id : SV_DispatchThreadID)
{
   int shift_ind;
   int spread_len = spread.Length;
   int spread_shift = (spread_len - 1) / 2u;

   if (id.x == 0 | id.x == (uint)(x_count - 1)) { data[id.x + id.y * x_count] = border_coef; }
   else { data[id.x + id.y * x_count] += border_coef_arr[id.x]; }
   
   for (int s = 0; s < spread_len; s++)
   {
       shift_ind = id.x + s - spread_shift;

       if (shift_ind > (x_count - 1)) continue;
       else if (shift_ind < 0) continue;

       data[id.x + (id.y + 1) * x_count] += data[shift_ind + id.y * x_count] * spread[s];
   }
   
   GroupMemoryBarrierWithGroupSync();
}
```

if i call the method like:

```
shader.Dispatch (spreading_index, x_count / 25, z_count - 1, 1);
```

and

```
[numthreads (25, 1, 1)]
void Spreading (uint3 id: SV_DispatchThreadID)
```

It starts to work much faster, but the result is not correct.

What am I doing wrong and what can I do about it?

Answer (score 2):

Writing efficient compute shaders is hard, you need to understand how the hardware works, and even then it's usually not an easy task to write a compute shader that is efficient and correct for complex algorithms, due to the way multithreading works on GPUs.

1. Your GPU will split the work across *wave fonts*, which are essentailly arrays of threads - usually 32 or 64 threads per wave font (32 is the most common. Only some AMD GPUs have 64). Each wave font can only execute a single thread group at once. By specifying `[numthreads(1, 1, 1)]`, you are saying that a thread group contains just a single thread (1 x 1 x 1), so of all those 32/64 threads in the wave font, only one will do actual work, while the rest of threads is idle (as they can't execute a different group in the meantime). This is why your compute shader is so slow: You are, at most, using only 1/32 of your GPU. Ideally, you would want your group size to be a multiple of the wave font size, so something like `[numthreads(32, 1, 1)]` or `[numthreads(64, 1, 1)]` will reach best performance (depending on your GPU).
2. `GroupMemoryBarrierWithGroupSync()` only syncs between threads *in a group*. So if your group just contains one thread, this will do nothing, and if it contains multiple threads, it obviously doesn't do what you think it does.
3. What `GroupMemoryBarrierWithGroupSync()` actually does is that it guarantees that all work *before* that line *inside this group* will be executed before anything after that line is being executed. So it will never sync all your 1.2 million threads with each other, only small sub sections of them, and it only splits work between 'before' and 'after' that line.
4. If I understand your code correctly, each entry in your data array contains a weighted sum of multiple entries from the previous row. Doing such a operation in a single compute shader dispatch is extremely difficult (though maybe not impossible, if you use some information and tricks very smartly), because each thread needs to read *multiple* values that other threads might be currently writing to, and that access pattern is not tightly contained. As an easier solution, I would recommend that your compute shader just processes a single row at a time (each thread just computes a single entry in your array, and all threads have the same y value as input), and then you just do multiple `shader.Dispatch(...)` calls (one per row). This way, you can sync one dispatch call with the next one using UAV Barriers (depending on the API you're using, these barriers might be inserted automatically, or you have to insert them manually), and no thread of your compute shader could potentially read a value that another thread is currently writing to.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.
Let me find out a few more points.

1. - 3. yes, now I understand why the order was out of order when the thread was in more than one and many groups. And the GroupMemoryBarrierWithGroupSync () didn't really help me, it just couldn't help.

4. In an attempt to speed up the work, I tried a lot of variants:
- to begin with, eliminated multiple reads and writes to the buffer by introducing an intermediate value.

Comment: `float summ = 0.0f;
for (int s = 0; s < spread_len; s++)
{...
summ += data[shift_ind + step * x_count] * spread[s];
}
data[id.x + (step + 1) * x_count] += summ;
`
This has accelerated the process by more than 2 times.
- Then, as you wrote, I tried to make a loop in which I sent the index of the next layer.

`for (int step = 0; step < z_count - 20; step++)
{
shader.SetInt("step", step);
shader.Dispatch(spreading_index, x_count / 25, 1, 1);
}`
I tried to do 32 threads but it didn't give much speed up.
This also made it 2 times faster.

Comment: - I tried to cheat the order of streams by using protected writing and returning a value. So I thought I could manage orders.
`int index;
InterlockedAdd(temporal[0], 1, index);
InterlockedAdd(tamplate[index + x_count], tamplate[index] + 1);`




But it didn't work out. If I ran many groups of 1 thread, it worked, otherwise it didn't. 
Why didn't this option work?

What would you advise to read about the use of UAV barriers? I'm new to all of this, currently using Unity for work.

Comment: @DenisFirsov 'cheating' order is problematic because, for one, you don't want too much order (things should still happen in parallel), and on top of that: Threads in a wave font don't have order. This is the actual reason why all threads in a wave font have to execute the same group, a wave font of (for example 32) threads is actually just a single SIMD unit, so all those 32 threads *always* execute the exact same instruction at the exact same time. This, of course, means that you can't enfore an order between those threads at all.

Comment: Regarding UAV Barriers: As far as I can tell, unity does handle them under the hood, so you don't have to worry about them too much. These barriers are insert between dispatch calls, and ensure that all threads from the previous dispatch have been executed on the GPU before the first threads of the next dispatch are started (so, it's kind of a global wait for threads on the GPU). They are just one kind of resource barrier that can be used.

Comment: If you really want to read about it, you'd have to dig into how Vulkan or DX12 does resource barriers/transitions, but if you just use Unity, you don't really have to worry about it, it's more of a low level thing.

Comment: Also, it's not surprising that the difference between using 25 or 32 threads per group isn't that much in terms of performance, because 25 is already kind of close to 32, and since more threads also mean more memory access and higher pressure on the cache lines, there can easily be some kind of deminishing returns with increasing the thread count above a certain point (tho the point depends on your shader and on your hardware).